# After call ExternalInterface.addCallback do i need to remove it?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

AFter call `ExternalInterface.addCallback`, do i need to

```
ExternalInterface.addCallback("foo", null);
```

since i will use `ExternalInterface.call` many times?

this is my method

```
    public static function javascript(jsFunctionYouWantCall:String, jsFunctionToBindResponse:String, onResponse:Function, jsFunctionYouWantCallParam:Object = null):Boolean
    {
        if (!ExternalInterface.available)
            return false;

        try
        {
            ExternalInterface.addCallback(jsFunctionToBindResponse, function response(param:Object):void
            {
                //ExternalInterface.addCallback(jsFunctionToBindResponse, null);
                onResponse(param);
            });
            ExternalInterface.call(jsFunctionYouWantCall, jsFunctionYouWantCallParam);
        }
        catch(error:Error) 
        {
            onResponse(error);
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, don't remove it if you plan on having the page access the swf again through the same js function call.  If it's not there, your external javascript call won't work.

Why were you concerned about removing it?

Comment: because every time i re-add it.

Comment: No, don't re-add it.  You just need to add it once.